# Can I use JDK for commercial use?

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer and very interested in the topic of paid or free software, so ask about jdk. I know it's free for personal use, but if I create an Android app and upload it to the store or sell it to someone, do I must to pay money to Oracle because I downloaded jdk, or is it free for commercial use?.

Comment: see https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/oracle-jdk-faqs.html.

Comment: See this [Oracle JDK License](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/oracle-jdk-faqs.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing, not programming. See also: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica: I would *not* close it. The question doesn't show much investigation effort. You are free to downvote it. But the question is very close to programming: How can you start programming Java, if you don't know what JDK you may / can / should use? With your reasoning would you also close any questions about Eclipse, IDEA, Maven, Gradle, etc.?

Comment: [Related Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240883/where-to-ask-legal-questions-on-programming).

Answer (score 4):

Better to check the official documentation: [Oracle Java SE Licensing FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/oracle-jdk-faqs.html).

> Is Java still free?
>
> Yes. For over a decade, Oracle stewards the OpenJDK open source community and provides the latest stability, performance and security updates to the latest release. This includes patch updates, scheduled over a year in advance; additional updates when required; and two feature updates (which also include critical patch updates) each year under the new release cadence. Our contributions are available to be ported, analysed, and used by anyone, as open source. You can download the latest OpenJDK release of Java from Oracle, for free, under an open source license from jdk.java.net.

However...

> If you are an organization used to getting Oracle Java SE binaries at no cost, you can simply continue doing so with Oracle's OpenJDK releases available at jdk.java.net. If you are used to getting Oracle Java SE binaries at no cost as a personal user or for development use, then you can continue to get Oracle Java SE releases through java.com (personal users) and the Oracle Technology Network (“OTN”) (developers). Those wishing to use the Oracle JDK or Oracle JRE for other uses will require a Java SE Subscription. Supported customers of Oracle products can continue to get their Oracle Java SE binaries from My Oracle Support (MOS) or Oracle Software Delivery Cloud (customers), and other locations.